# Android custom action bar with action buttons

Tags: android, width, android-actionbar, menuitem

Here is the action bar that I want to create.

[image]

Here is items that I put in menu.

```
   <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/search_layout"
    />

     <item
        android:id="@+id/search1"
        android:title="PHOTO"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/search_layout"
    />
```

collapseActionView - collapses search menu on startup.

[image]
After click on search item it shows edit text like on picture 1. But I need always see it, not only after click.

If I set it to Always it will pop the menu items from the screen because of fill_parent.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_search"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Is it possible to get width of title bar layout without menu items? In this case I can set fixed width to edittext item.

Is it any other approaches to make it work? 
In result it must be custom title layout + menu items. This custom layout must fill empty space between menu items and icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting a custom view in place of the action bar title.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.search_layout);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

The result is an `EditText` that fills the entire width of the action bar, except for the action buttons. It looks exactly like the first image in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Using **Custom ActionBar**, you can solve your Problem. For **Custom ActionBar** you have to create on Custom Layout as per following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:enabled="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:paddingEnd="8dip"
android:paddingRight="8dip"
android:paddingLeft="8dip">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_edt_search"/>
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_img_search"
    android:background="@drawable/search_ico"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_search"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    style="@style/ActionBarButtonWhite" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_photo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    style="@style/ActionBarButtonOffWhite" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_video"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    style="@style/ActionBarButtonOffWhite" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_mobile"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    style="@style/ActionBarButtonOffWhite" />
```

**color.xml**

```
<resources>
<color name="action_bar">#ff0d0d0d</color>
<color name="white">#ffffffff</color>
<color name="off_white">#99ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">28dip</item>
</style>


<style name="ActionBarButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_small</item>
</style>
```

now you need to create **ViewGroup** and **ActionBar** in your java file as per following:

```
final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.actions,
            null);

    // Set up your ActionBar
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);


    // You customization

    final int actionBarColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(actionBarColor));

    final EditText actionBarEditSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_edt_search);
    actionBarEditSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    final ImageButton actionBarImgSearch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_img_search);
    actionBarImgSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    final Button actionBarSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_search);
    actionBarSearch.setText("SEARCH");

    final Button actionBarPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_photo);
    actionBarPhoto.setText("PHOTO");

    final Button actionBarVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_video);
    actionBarVideo.setText("VIDEO");

    final Button actionBarMobile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_mobile);
    actionBarMobile.setText("MOBILE");

    actionBarSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            actionBarEditSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            actionBarImgSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            actionBarSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    actionBarImgSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            actionBarEditSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            actionBarImgSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            actionBarSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });


<style name="ActionBarButtonWhite" parent="@style/ActionBarButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarButtonOffWhite" parent="@style/ActionBarButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/off_white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: if you need a custom action bar this is the best method.