# Action bar with custom title bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need action bar with custom title bar in android please help me,thanks.
The other option worth looking at is ActionBarCompat, which I think comes with the SDK 14 api demos. However, `ActionBarSherlock` seems to support many more features so that may be the better solution.

Comment: See this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291937/android-custom-action-bar-with-action-buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock is now kind of a "best practice" you are right in using it.

**Create your Menu in the folder with the same name for example :**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_filtre"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/menu_filtre"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_clear"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/menu_clear"/>
```

**then in your MainActivity for example :**

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.clear();
    switch ((int) _viewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
        case 0:
            getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            break;
        }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**And to finish :**

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
bar.setTitle(R.string.titre_abs);
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

For the installation take a look here 
http://actionbarsherlock.com/

For creating themes here
http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100

if you need more just ask

**good luck**